# Как вернуть данные, полученные из request (Alamofire, Swift)

Tags: swift, alamofire

Всем привет.
Столкнулся со следующей проблемой.
Не могу вернуть данные из Alamofire.request()

```
    request("myURl", method: .post, parameters: data).validate().responseJSON { responseJSON in
        switch responseJSON.result{
            case .success(let value):
                guard let jsonArray = responseJSON.result.value as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
                print(jsonArray)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
        }
    }
```

Как вернуть из request jsonArray?

Answer (score 1):

Создайте в Вашем классе метод, который будет получать данные из запроса:

```
func handleResponse(json: [[String: Any]]) {
    print(json)
    // MARK: - do some with response data
}
```

и передавайте в него:

```
case .success(let value):
    guard let jsonArray = responseJSON.result.value as? [[String: Any]] else { return }
    self.handleResponse(json: jsonArray)
```

После того, как запрос будет выполнен успешно, а данные подходящими, они будут переданы в вызванный `handleResponse`

Comment: Проблема осталась `func handleResponse(json: [Post]){
        self.response = json
        print("handleResponce = \(self.response)")
    }`. При попытке обратиться к response, допустим, из ViewController выдает пустое значение

Comment: @Алексей, Вы обращаетесь после завершения запроса? Запрос в сеть - длительная по времени операция и данные будут не сразу.